# Create and plot a piecewise function in Octave

Tags: plot, octave, piecewise

So I want to plot this function

[image]

for -1

First I created  the piecewise function

```
function x = pieceWise(t)
  if t >= 0 & t <3
    x = exp(-t);
  else
    x = 0;
endif
```

then called and plot it here

```
x = linspace(-1,5,1000);
y = pieceWise(x);
plot(x,y)
```

but the output is always 0

[image]

any hint would be very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should vectorize you code:

```
1;
function x = pieceWise(t)
  x = zeros (size (t));
  ind = t >= 0 & t < 3;
  x(ind) = exp(-t(ind));
endfunction

x = linspace (-1, 5, 1000);
y = pieceWise (x);
plot (x, y)
grid on
print out.p
```

gives

[image: result]